# Is it possible to change the prev/next pagination to numbering pagination in wordpress admin panel?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-admin

[image]

As the picture above illustrates, we are currently using only next/prev pagination buttons.
Now, I have to click arrows several times to find a post I wanna see.
The more posts are registered, the more annoying this process becomes.
So, I want to have the pagination with numbers.
Is there any simple way to solve this problem?

Comment: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-numeric-pagination-in-your-wordpress-theme/

Comment: @Pie I can do that in the front page, but I don't know how to figure it out in the admin posts panel.